# Is there any way to make Docker download public images faster?

Tags: docker

```
core@core-01 ~ $ docker run -p 3000:8080 paulbrennan/dillinger 
Unable to find image 'paulbrennan/dillinger' locally
Pulling repository paulbrennan/dillinger
0a8ed7d461a1: Pulling dependent layers 
511136ea3c5a: Download complete 
8cbdf71a8e7f: Downloading 2.162 MB/67.49 MB 14m19s
```

Is there any mirror or a way to add a mirror? Why is it so slow? My internet connect is very fast here in Hong Kong.

I think the problem might be my location, if I run this on an Amazon linux server it runs fast, however from my PC here in Hong Kong its slow.

Comment: I would love an answer to this. We have servers inside the great firewall of China and getting docker running is a pain because the public docker repo is blocked.

Comment: General best practice is to use docker on a remote server if you use it everyday. I have a digitalocean box dedicated to building and running docker containers. I know this probably isn't the answer you were looking for. Would be interested if someone has a local solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can push the images you need into a docker registry running in your own infrastructure.

The docker registry is itself a docker container so it's really easy to set it up.

https://github.com/docker/docker-registry

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at this article

Dockerizing an Apt-Cacher-ng Service

http://docs.docker.com/examples/apt-cacher-ng/

extract

This container makes the second download of any package almost instant.